# batch script with argument

Tags: batch-file, command-line-arguments, batch-processing

I'm relatively new to batch. I have written s small script which goes into some specific directories and execute a command (make):

```
FOR /d %%p IN (Test_*) do FOR /d %%s IN (%%p\*) do make clean --directory "%%s"
```

So Test_* means all directories which begins with Test_ .

I would like to call this script also with argument, so that I call this command also when I specify a directory, for example, something like this:

myScript.bat Test_XY

The code should be something like this:

```
SET Modus=%1
IF "%Modus%"==""(
FOR /d %%p IN (Test_*) do FOR /d %%s IN (%%p\*) do make clean --directory "%%s" 
)
ELSE
FOR /d %%p IN (%1) do FOR /d %%s IN (%%p\*) do make clean --directory "%%s"
```

but I get the error that the syntax is not valid

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There is a SPACE missing in the line `IF "%Modus%"=="" (` (between `""` and `(`); and the `ELSE` must be in the same line as the `)` above (separated by a space);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unlike other variants of the FOR command you must include a wildcard
>   (either * or ?) in the 'folder_set' to get consistent results
>   returned. http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html

```dos
SET Modus=%1
IF "%Modus%"=="" (
    FOR /d %%p IN (Test_*) do (
        FOR /d %%s IN (%%p\*) do make clean --directory "%%s"
    ) 
) ELSE (
    FOR /d %%p IN (%Modus%) do (
        FOR /d %%s IN (%%p\*) do make clean --directory "%%s"
    )
)
```

I would rewrite to this:

```dos
set "modus=%1"
if "%modus%"=="" (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%p in ('dir /b /a:d "Test_*"') do (
        echo make clean --directory "%%p"
    )
) else (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%p in ('dir /b /a:d "%modus%"') do (
        echo make clean --directory "%%p"
    )
)
```

More simple and compact

```dos
set "modus=%1"
if "%modus%"=="" set "modus=Test_*"
for /f "tokens=*" %%p in ('dir /b /a:d "%modus%"') do (
    echo make clean --directory "%%p"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
 set var=%1
IF [%1]==[] set "var=Test_*"    
FOR /d %%p IN (%var%) do FOR /d %%s IN (%%p\*) do make clean --directory "%%s"
```

and call the batch script like

```
myscript.bat Test_XY
```

`%1` is for first argument.. if you want to use multiple argument then use `%1`, `%2`, `%3`... and so on.

Comment: Ok, that's working. But I would like also to keep the command to do it for all directories (when I call the script without argument) ?

Comment: This works with arguments but if i run the script without argument, I get the error: 'var is not recognized as an internal or external command'

Comment: ups - found another typo. Try again please.

Answer (score 0):

To execute your batch file as shown, in a specific folder,
passing the folder on the command line - you have these two options at least.

1:

```
@echo off
cd /d "%~1"
FOR /d %%p IN (Test_*) do FOR /d %%s IN (%%p\*) do make clean --directory "%%s"
```

2:

```
@echo off
pushd "%~1"
FOR /d %%p IN (Test_*) do FOR /d %%s IN (%%p\*) do make clean --directory "%%s" 
popd
```